# Unable to extract CSRF token from html body in Cypress

Tags: html-parsing, csrf, cypress, csrf-token

I am unable to parse CSRF token from html in Cypress. 
I am following this link : [Logging in using CSRF Token in Cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/logging-in__csrf-tokens)

Trying to follow **strategy #1** in the above link but I keep getting token as undefined.

This is how my html looks like:

[Return html looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekIxx.jpg)

This is how my code looks like:

```
           cy.request({
                url: returnUrlFromLoginAPI,
                followRedirect: false
            })
            .its('body')
            .then((body) => {
                const $html = Cypress.$(body)
                const requestVerificationToken = $html.find("input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]").val()
                console.log(requestVerificationToken)
             })
        })
```

Comment: does `$html.find` actually returns a result? I tried the same with querying for a meta tag and it didn't work.

Comment: It did work for me. I was able to find the element by $html.find.

Answer (score 0):

`.find` looks for descendants for the current elements set and my meta tag was part of this set and not a descendant. that's why you should use `.filter`, cause filter looks for current set and its descendants

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the "correct" way is, but I did this:

```
cy.get('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').then($rvt => {
   console.log($rvt.val());
}
```